# How to get cart subtotal without tax in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, tax

How can I retrieve the cart subtotal without tax in Magento 2?

Comment: In Mini cart and shopping cart page?

Comment: I'm trying to get it from my custom shipping method. I need to enable or disable my shipping method based on cart subtotal without tax.

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total` to get the total.

```
/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total **/

$total->getSubtotal(); // Subtotal excluded tax
$total->getSubtotalInclTax() // Subtotal included tax.
```

Comment: `$total->getSubtotalInclTax()` is working, but its including tax, but `$total->getSubtotal()` did not work for me. I have tried. :(

Comment: `$total->getSubtotal()` returns value?

Comment: No, it does not return anything, not even error or `null` it just blank.

Comment: You should add full code lines.

Comment: Thanks, I will try one more time and, let you know the feedback.

Comment: You should dump out the `$total->getData()` to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add this plugin in your code and after that you will get $total->getSubtotal(),$total->getSubtotalInclTax() and $total->getSubtotalExclTax()

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;


class TaxPlugin
{
    /**
     * Tax configuration object
     *
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_config;

    /**
     * TaxPlugin constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig
    )
    {
        $this->_config = $taxConfig;
    }

    /**
     * add subtotal inclusive of tax
     *
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param $quote
     * @param $total
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterFetch(\Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax $subject, $result, $quote, $total)
    {
        $store = $quote->getStore();
        $amount = $total->getTaxAmount();
        if ($amount === null) {
            $this->enhanceTotalData($quote, $total);
            $amount = $total->getTaxAmount();
        }
        $taxAmount = $amount + $total->getTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation');

        if (!($this->_config->displayCartSubtotalBoth($store) || $this->_config->displayCartSubtotalInclTax($store))) {
            if ($total->getSubtotalInclTax() > 0) {
                $subtotalInclTax = $total->getSubtotalInclTax();
            } else {
                $subtotalInclTax = $total->getSubtotal() + $taxAmount - $total->getShippingTaxAmount();
            }

            $result[] = [
                'code' => 'subtotal',
                'title' => __('Subtotal'),
                'value' => $total->getSubtotal(),
                'value_incl_tax' => $subtotalInclTax,
                'value_excl_tax' => $total->getSubtotal(),
            ];
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```